# Alarm broadcastIntent is killed after some time on Android OS

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-pendingintent

I am developing app similiar to alarm clock. I am using Android 4.2.2.

The problem is that after some time (about 1 or 2 hours) alarm pendingIntent is killed by something.

The sequence is:
1. SetAlarm() to trigger after 2 hours.
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentToFire, 0);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, alarmIntent);
2. I see that Alarm has been set up throw "adb shell dumpsys alarm". +1h59m left
3. After 10 minutes...I see that Alarm has been set up throw "adb shell dumpsys alarm".+1h49m left
4. After 20 minutes...I see that Alarm has been set up throw "adb shell dumpsys alarm".+1h39m left
5. And so on...
6. Then after about 1-2 h. (differenet time) Oooops. There is no my alarm pendingIntent in the "adb shell dumpsys alarm" list.

Android native alarm clock works OK.

UPD: code

Broadcast Receiver registered in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name=".BrdRcvr" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>        
            <action android:name="action.alarm.RI" />
            <action android:name="action.alarm.ERT0" />
            <action android:name="action.alarm.ERT1" />
            <action android:name="action.alarm.ERT2" />
            <action android:name="action.alarm.ERT3" />
            <action android:name="action.alarm.ERT4" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Function to set Alarm

```
public static void setAlarmRI(Context context) {
    //Read time from preferences
    SharedPreferences appPref = 
            context.getSharedPreferences(SettingsActivity.APP_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    int timeToAlarmMs = Integer.valueOf(appPref.getInt(SettingsActivity.APP_PREF_RI, 0)) * 1000; //[ms]

    //!getSystemService must be called after onCreate() 
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeToAlarmMs * 60; //[min]

    //Intent
    Intent intentToFire = new Intent(context, BrdRcvr.class);
    intentToFire.setAction("action.alarm.RI");

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
            0, intentToFire, 0/*flags*/);

    if (timeToAlarmMs > 0) {
        //for API >= 19 AlarmManager.set() triggers not at exact time (for battery saving)
        //and we should use AlarmManager.setExact() instead
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, alarmIntent);
        else
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, alarmIntent);

        Log.d(ALARMRI, "API:" + Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT).toString());
        Log.d(ALARMRI, "set:" + Long.valueOf(time).toString());
        Log.d(ALARMRI, "cur:" + Long.valueOf(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()).toString());
        Log.d(ALARMRI, "delta:" + (Long.valueOf(time) -
                Long.valueOf(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())));
    } else {
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
        Log.d(ALARMRI, "unset");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Skynet, my code is just standard code. Nothing unusual.

Comment: It would still be worthwhile to have a look :)

Comment: post your code... if the problem is where you expected it to be, you probably would have solved this already...

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't canceling the alarm yourself? Does your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` get called? Are you sure?

Comment: To David Wasser. 1. Yes, I am sure that I am not canceling alarm by myself. I have commented cancellation and nothing have changed. 2. Yes, my BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() is called. I see it in the logCat.